# Do Lists "loop back" in such a fashion?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, slice

Consider the following code:

```
def mystr(L):
   print(L[0])
   return L[-1]

mystery_list = [2,5]
print(mystr(mystery_list))

Output (stdout):
2
5
```

I figure Python, once it goes into the negative zones, starts counting backwards? Therefore [-1] is the last element, [-2] is the second last element. Am I correct in this?

Does this behavior exist elsewhere in Python (ie: strings)?

If I create a copy of this list and I started at a negative number to 0 - will the list be inverted? ie newList = [-1:0] <-- will this invert the list?

Thanks.

Comment: You could simply try doing what you described and answer your question on your own...

Comment: Is your question the one about slicing/reversing a list or what? Yes, negative indices count from right. Yes, indexing is generally applicable to strings instead of lists -- anything with the methods that support it. And no, that will not reverse a list because the 'step' is still positive. Reverse is `[::-1]`.

Comment: Python does allow negative indexing into lists and sequence-like objects (tuples, strings, deques, etc.).

Comment: Support for negative indexes depends on the __getitem__ method of the class.  AFAIK, all CPython built-in classes have this.  Note that itertools.islice does not support negative indexes, but then, unbounded iterables may not even have a 'right end'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indexing with a negative number is relative to the end of the list.  This applies to python all python [sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) (and a number of other objects that aim to behave like sequences).

If slicing is defined as `sequence[i:j]`, then, according to the linked documentation

> If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string: `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that `-0` is still `0`.

Some examples of sequences are:

- string
- unicode
- tuple
- list
- xrange
- bytearray

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in this assumption. Strings, tuples, lists, or any sequence all conform to this behavior and support negative indexing. Example:

> ```
> Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
> [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
> >>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> >>> b = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> >>> c = "12345"
> >>> print(a[-1])
> 5
> >>> print(b[-1])
> 5
> >>> print(c[-1])
> 5
> ```